closed form for $\frac{2x+x^2+x^3}{1-x-x^3}$
I'm trying to find a "closed formula" for this generating function $\frac{2x+x^2+x^3}{1-x-x^3}$.
I thought about calculating the roots of $1-x-x^3$, but that definitely complicates the problem a lot, so my idea is to take the geometric series $$\frac{1}{1-(x+x^3)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x+x^3)^n.$$  Then, using the binomial theorem $$(x+x^3)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} x^{n+2k},$$ like this: $$\frac{1}{1-x-x^3}=\sum _{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^{n+2k},$$ and $$\frac{2x+ x^2+x^3}{1-x-x^3}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (2x^{n+2k+1}+x^{n+2k+2}+x^{n+2k+3})$$
This is the point I am at, I don't know if the idea is correct or is there some simpler way to do it?  address the problem.
Or is there any idea to continue with the calculation? since I'm a bit stuck, I'm probably missing some identity that can help me simplify the expression.
Edit 1:
By closed formula I mean some function of the type $n\mapsto a_n$, where $a_n$ is the $n$th coefficient of the power series associated with the initial generating function

What do you mean by a closed form? Do you want an expression for the coefficient of $x^n$ for example? Or something else? If the latter, can you provide an example for the type of thing you are looking for?

Another thing you could do, in theory, is a partial fraction decomposition. This would involve factoring $1 - x - x^3$, which does not have rational roots, so you can expect the factors to not be pretty. The result will be a nasty sum of three geometric series, plus an additional constant term. This is not a recommendation to go down this path, but more of an explanation about why the closed form I think you're looking for will be extremely nasty.

@TheoBendit. The sequence appeared for first time in year 1356 !!

@HackR I have added to the question what I mean by "closed formula"

You can write it as $-1 - \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^2(1-x-x^3)}$, but I'm not sure whether this counts as a “simplification”.

https://oeis.org/A000930 gives an explicit formula:
$$a_n = \lfloor dc^n + 1/2\rfloor,$$ where $c$ is the real root of $x^3-x^2-1$ and $d$ is the real root of $31x^3-31x^2+9x-1$.
